# Does a copy Dragon Age: Inquisition bought and activated elsewhere work in India?

Tags: origin, dragon-age-inquisition, region-lock

Dragon Age: Inquisition is not sold in India, for conformance with 'local content laws'. Fallout 3 was in a similar situation, and getting a friend in the US to buy and gift it to me worked with Steam's region-locking.

Will something similar work for Origin and Dragon Age: Inquisition? I can get a friend to buy it from the US Origin store and send me the key, or even activate it on my account. In addition, are the online features also region-locked? I am okay with multiplayer not working, but would like it if the online save import/export feature worked. Is any of this against the terms of service for Origin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bought an online code from US Amazon (had to fake my billing address with US zip code, but everything else worked fine).

After that I was able to activate it myself, and all features working, including multi-player and patches.

(just to clarify, I'm not in India but in a similarly region-locked country in Europe)